# Bouncycastle - how to get attached file from detached signature file

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I have myCMS CMSSignedData, but it only contains info about signatures, and no content (because it is detached)
Now i want to get full attached, using this myCMS, how to do that?

```
            byte[] cmsData = fileService.getBlobByPathAsBytes(docId, NuxeoConstants.PROPERTY_SIGNATURES_FILES, index, client);
            CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(cmsData);
            SignerInformationStore signerInformationStore = cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos();
            SignerInformation signerInformation = (SignerInformation) signerInformationStore.getSigners().stream().findFirst().get();
            Attribute signedFileNamesAttr = signerInformation.getSignedAttributes().get(new DERObjectIdentifier(FILE_NAMES_ATTR));
            DERSet derSet = (DERSet) signedFileNamesAttr.getAttrValues();
            String signedFileNamesStr = String.valueOf(derSet.getObjectAt(0));
            String[] signedFileNames = signedFileNamesStr.split("<>");

            ByteArrayOutputStream allFileBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            for (String signedFileName : signedFileNames) {
                if (!files.containsKey(signedFileName)) {
                    throw new RedoException(String.format("Не найден файл %s для проверки подписи", signedFileName));
                }
                allFileBytes.write(files.get(signedFileName));
            }

            byte[] srcData = allFileBytes.toByteArray();
```

Then I tried to this way to get Content:

```
            CMSSignedData myCMS = CMSUtil.parseAsCMS(cmsData);
            boolean isExternal = myCMS.getSignedContent() == null;
            if (isExternal) {
                CMSProcessableByteArray data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(srcData);
                myCMS = new CMSSignedData(data, cmsData);
            }
```